# OpenVINO installation on Raspbian - usbboot.rules file issue

Tags: installation, raspbian, opencv

I am attempting to install OpenVINO on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to use the Neural Compute Stick 2. They just recently released support for this and I am following the installation instructions here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-RaspberryPI

First, I did have an issue with running this command, #4 in the Install the Package section:

```
sed -i "s|<INSTALLDIR>|$(pwd)/inference_engine_vpu_arm|" inference_engine_vpu_arm/bin/setupvars.sh
```

It would tell me there was a syntax error after I went to the next step and so I edited this file (setupvars.sh) manually with the directory - is that accurate? It seemed to work ok:

```
INSTALLDIR=~/Downloads
```

However, the real issue I'm running into now is at step 2 in the Add USB Rules section:

```
sh inference_engine_vpu_arm/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh
```

Gives me this error:

```
Update udev rules so that the toolkit can communicate with your neural compute stick
File '97-myriad-usbboot.rules' is missing. Please check that you installed 'Inference Engine Runtime for Intel® Movidius™ VPU'.
inference_engine_vpu_arm/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh: 30: exit: Illegal number: -1
```

I see there is something similar in step 3 of the Get Started guide for Linux, though this doesn't seem to work for me either (I did change the name of the created file to match the error message, 97-myraid-usbboot.rules):
https://software.intel.com/en-us/neural-compute-stick/get-started

I've also tried to do this and run _install_all_dependencies.sh but get "command not found" errors for each action it tries to take.

I have also asked this question in the Intel Forum here (it is waiting approval from a moderator to be posted so not up at the time I'm posting here):
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/computer-vision

**Update**
Ok, well it was something to do with the path. I opened the file and replaced the line with the absolute path which allowed me to proceed. I'm assuming now this path issue (that I mentioned first here) is going to cause me more problems, did I include the path wrong?

Now I'm getting new errors when trying to run the Sample that comes with this package. 
Should I start a new question or add it here?

Comment: An excellent job of documenting your problem, and explaining the steps you took trying to solve it yourself (gasp!). ;-) Keep posting and good luck.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same problem today while trying to get OpenVino installed on my Raspberry Pi 3. For some reason, the instructions on the website fail to mention that the install directory(which is the part that you have to edit manually in the setupvars.sh) should be the same folder as the files(ie. /home/pi/Downloads/inference_engine_vpu_arm/) or else the paths set in all the other scripts are wrong. Once this is set to the folder, all the rest of the scripts run perfectly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did help, thank you so much! On my way with the sample now :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look directly at the sh file:

```bsh
echo "Updating udev rules..."
if [ -z "$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Please set up your environment. Run 'source <OPENVINO_INSTALLDIR>/bin/setupvars.sh'."
    exit -1
fi

if [ -f "$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/97-myriad-usbboot.rules" ]; then
    sudo usermod -a -G users "$(whoami)"

    sudo cp "$INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR/deployment_tools/inference_engine/external/97-myriad-usbboot.rules" /etc/udev/rules.d/
    sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
    sudo udevadm trigger
    sudo ldconfig
    echo "Udev rules have been successfully installed."
else
    echo "File '97-myriad-usbboot.rules' is missing. Please make sure you installed 'Inference Engine Runtime for Intel® Movidius™ VPU'."
    exit -1
fi
```

This script is simple, it just checks if the file exists and then copies and updates.

I prefer to specify the corresponding directory directly at the script file beginning, like this:

```bsh
INTEL_OPENVINO_DIR=/opt/intel/openvino_2021
echo "Updating udev rules..."
# ...
```

Then just run it again.

> Note that in some self-compiled versions this rule file may not be included, but you can still get it from the official release and it is actually version-independent.