# OpenVINO installation on rasbian

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am installing openvino on rasbian using VNC viewer and the intel neural stick 2 which is installed on the raspberry pi https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-RaspberryPI.

I have an issue when i get to the step "Add USB Rules" of that step 2 which says

*"To perform inference on the Intel® Movidius™ Neural Compute Stick or Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2, install the USB rules as follows:*

```
sh inference_engine_vpu_arm/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh"
```

i am getting the following error

```
File '97-myriad-usbboot.rules' is missing. Please check that you installed 'Inference Engine Runtime for Intel® Movidius™ VPU'.
inference_engine_vpu_arm/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh: 30: exit: Illegal number: -1
```

Should i change the file labelled ***install_NCS_udev_rules.sh***
 or should i change something else. I am executing this command from the *`Downloads`* directory  . Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: did you try searching on your system to see if that file is available? The command `sudo find / -name '97-myriad-usbboot.rules'` should emit something like `/the/crazy/path/to/'97-myriad-usbboot.rules'`. If not, then your install didn't work right to begin with. If you did get back a valid path, then you need to figure why the install process can't see it. There could be many reasons, but all boiling down to the idea that the installer has to be started from the right place, and that it has to have a correct list of dirs to search for the needed script. `echo $PATH` shows your current set.

Comment: I have no knowledge of this installer program, so won't be able to help further, AND I would recommend that for rPi issues, better to post to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. You may find something helpful in another Q here about Vino/Movidius : https://superuser.com/questions/1388854/openvino-installation-on-raspbian-usbboot-rules-file-issue  Good luck.